# java How to convert Document to String.But the empty tag is <></>,isn't </>

Tags: java, xml, dom

In my project ,my company requires empty tag use `<a></a>` form ,rather than `<a/>` form. And Haven't redundant enters and spaces. But I don't know how to do it. You can use any way to do it.

Here is I generate xml(String) from Document:

```
< Header>< Fund_Id>1< /Fund_Id>< Trade_Code/>< Error_Code/>< Error_Message/>< /Header>
```

To the empty tags, I want it is  form.
example:

```
< Header>< Fund_Id>1< /Fund_Id>< Trade_Code>< /Trade_Code>< Error_Code>< /Error_Code>< Error_Message>< /Error_Message>< /Header>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post an example and more information.

What DOES your data look like, and what SHOULD it look like

Comment: Please be clear, post some example http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this XML or HTML you are talking about?  'Cos your example could be either, and the rules / technologies are not identical.

Comment: You can always do the conversion from `<x/>` to `<x></x>` after you produce the `String`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I  added more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my question by this methods.  Convert the String after converting Document to String.

```
public static String xmlChange(String xmlStr)
{
    if(xmlStr!=null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlStr.length();)
        {
            int index=xmlStr.indexOf("/>",i);
            if(index>0)
            {
                String tempStr = xmlStr.substring(i, index + 2);
                int leftIndex=tempStr.lastIndexOf("<");
                String old= tempStr.substring(leftIndex);
                String _new=old.replace("/","")+old.replace("/","").replace("<","</");
                i=index+2;
                xmlStr=xmlStr.replace(old,_new);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        xmlStr=xmlStr.replaceAll("\r|\n", "");
    }
    return xmlStr;
}
```